# VB.net If or statement

Tags: vb.net, string

I have a textbox that people enter a number or a range, eg 12-15, and a random number is generated. Currently if the second number is less than the first I can get it to work how I want but not if only a single number is listed.

rnum1 should equal rnum2 if there isn't a words(1) or if it's less than words(0). (I do have it done if it's less.)

```
Dim words As String() = TextBox2.Text.Split("-")
Dim rnum1 As String = words(0)
Dim rnum2 As String = words(1)
Dim RandomClass As New Random()
Dim RandomNumber As Integer

If rnum2 < rnum1 Then
rnum2 = rnum1

End If

RandomNumber = RandomClass.Next(rnum1, rnum2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this line

```
Dim rnum2 As String = words(1)
```

to

```
Dim rnum2 As String = IF(words.Length = 2, words(1), rnum1)
```

It checks whether there're 2 elements in words array. If it is - it uses second element of array, otherwise it reassigns the first.

Come to think of it, this can be achieved even by this:

```
Dim rnum2 As String = words(words.Length - 1)
```

If there're 2 elements in the array - it will assign words(1), otherwise words(0)

Comment: Thanks Yuriy that worked perfectly but it seems my If ... then ... isn't working after all.

Comment: Try changing type of rnum1 and rnum2 from String to Integer. This way they will be compared as numbers.